# Perl warnings, strict & diagnostic errors are not output when using utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have installed Strawberry Perl 5.22 on Windows 7 then Padre/Dwimperl (which includes Strawberry 5.14). I then uninstalled 5.22. Then I installed SDL using "cpan SDL" from "D:\Dwimperl\perl\bin". It appeared to install correctly.

Using Padre (and/or the command line) I can run Perl scripts. However, if I introduce an error ("$r=0;") then I will not see the normal output from warnings/strict/diagnostics unless I comment out "use utf8;"

With "use utf8;" I get this un-helpful error:

```
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at D:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/diagnos
tics.pm line 599.
```

Without it I get this more helpful error:

```
Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name at sdl2.pl line 12.
Execution of sdl2.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"),

    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Global symbol "$r" requires explicit package name at sdl2.pl line 12.
Execution of sdl2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
 at sdl2.pl line 15
```

This is the script I am using:

```
#! D:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
$r = 0;
print "Hello World!\n";
exit 0;
```

Can anyone advise how I can keep the useful errors and also use utf8?

Comment: No, @Raju! He __intentionally__ omitted it to produce an error. The OP's problem is that the error isn't properly reported when he uses utf8.

Comment: I tend to avoid `use diagnostics`.  All it really does is take the output of `use warnings` and looks it up in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) to print out instead, which would be great and all if most Editors & IDEs weren't actually *looking* for the output of the `warnings` module to highlight you problems.

Comment: @BlueGF, If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Comment: Thanks for that advice @tjd I now comment out "use diagnostics". If I have a problem I can't figure out then I will go search the internet anyway to get more info. The alternate is to upgrade to a newer version of Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and happens outside Strawberry Perl. Check out this post:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=884018

Comment: It was fixed in 5.16